# After creating table it shows this Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

After creating table using exec() in PDO,it shows like this

```
Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )
```

Is this an error or did I successfully create my table?
When I looked up in the database the table is created.

this is what i executed

```
try{

    $tbl = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDB",'root',''); 
     $tbl->exec("CREATE TABLE test(fld1 CHAR(40),fld2 CHAR(40))")
     or die(print_r($tbl->errorInfo(),true));
   }
catch(Exception $e){
     echo $e.getMessage();
 }
```

@Vikas,correct me if i am wrong.and this is working

```
    $queryTBl="CREATE TABLE test(fld1 CHAR(40),fld2 CHAR(40))";

    $evaluateTBL=tbl->exec($queryTBL);

    if ($evaluateTBL===false)
         print "Test table could not be created";
    else
         print "Successfully Created";
```

Comment: What is that the output of?  exec() returns an int (or boolean false).

Comment: @Corbin: it looks like the output of [`PDO::errorInfo`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php). Most likely, OP is using `==` instead of `===` when checking the `PDO::exec` return value.

Comment: The output is from `PDO::errorInfo`. Most probably because table is already created when you ran the script for the first time. Subsequent run is failing.

Comment: @Vikas,No in my first attempt it show like that,and i did it second time and the message is test table is already exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [PDO::exec manual](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php) it returns number of rows affected by the query. And there is no rows affected by a `CREATE` query. So `exec` for this query will return 0 even if it was successful. And it will be evaluated `false`. This explains why `die` is called even when there is no error.

It is better to either rely on exception or do a `=== false` on return code of exec to decide if it failed. From the manual:

> This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.

Example of doing the same thing with exceptions:

```
try {
  $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDB",'root','');
  $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  $connection->exec('CREATE TABLE test(fld1 CHAR(40),fld2 CHAR(40))');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  <handle exception>
}
```

Comment: @jemz, yes but PDO by default doesn't throw exception. You need to use [PDO::setAttribute](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) to set `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` to `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` to make it throw exceptions.

Comment: where to put the setAttribute so that it will throw exception iside my Try statement?