# PDO not creating CREATE TABLE

Tags: php, sql, pdo, create-table

I'm pretty new to this and need some help.

I am trying to input an array into a PDO database; the database is created using this code:

```
$createdb = $db->exec("CREATE DATABASE $validdbname;
CREATE USER '$user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$password';
GRANT ALL ON `$validdbname` .* TO '$user'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;")
or die(print_r($db->errorInfo(), true));
// Check for success
if ($createdb) 
{
    echo 'Database Created!<br /><br />';
}
else echo "Database not successfully created! <br /><br />";
```

This works successfully, however when I attempt to create a table within the created database with very similar code, this does not work:

```
$createtable = $db->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS webdata (
id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
data VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id))")

or die(print_r($db->errorInfo(), true));
```

I have checked on PHPMyAdmin to see if a table has been created, which while databases have been created the tables aren't.  This is the error that shows:

```
Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )
```

I would be happy to give more code or information if necessary.  I just cannot work out why this is happening and would greatly appreciate any input, thanks.

Comment: This looks a very similar problem:
[link]
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562602/after-creating-table-it-shows-this-array-0-00000-1-2)[link]

Comment: Error handling for pdo is different from old mysql. Connect as described in [PDO tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) and you will need no `or die()` stuff yet have your error revealed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to

```
$db->exec('USE ' . $validdbname);
```

between the two queries, or use a fully qualified name in the `CREATE TABLE`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $validdbname.webdata ( ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, I have just tried these suggestions on the code and have received the same error again still. Sorry to be a nuisance.

Comment: @CamWestwood Try running the `CREATE TABLE` immediately after the `CREATE DATABASE` (i.e. before messing around with the privileges).

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried that with this line of code (below), based on your suggestions above and it works now.

$connect = $db->exec("USE $validdbname;");